# Getting character count for each row in text doc

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the character count for each row in a text doc.  The contents of my text doc are:

```
1
15
69
124
300
```

I've been trying variants of the PS script:

```
get-content c:\serverlist.txt | foreach-object {measure-object -character}
```

But the best I can get returned is:

Lines     Words     Characters   Property
-------     --------     --------------   -----------
                                            0
                                            0
                                            0
                                            0
                                            0

Not sure what I'm missing here, but any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to pipe directly into `Measure-Object`:

```
Get-Content c:\serverlist.txt | Measure-Object -Character
```

Otherwise you'd have to do either

```
| ForEach-Object { $_ | Measure-Object -Character }
```

which would be a bit of weird use of the pipeline or

```
| ForEach-Object { Measure-Object -Character -InputObject $_ }
```

which would be just about the same as the variant above.

Comment: Perfect!  Both the second and third choices give me what I'm looking for.  Just didn't know the context.

Thanks Johannes!